# What is a positive question record?

Tags: support, asking-questions, badges

What is a positive question record?

Some of the badges need positive question record what is it? And how can I earn it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is determined based on how many, or rather how few, of your questions get closed, deleted, and have negative score. You do not need to do anything in particular, it's a side-effect.

Specifically, [as I explained some time ago](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/23432/):

> [T]he criterion for having a positive question record is:
>
> $$Q_T \ge  2(Q_N + Q_C +  Q_D)$$
>
> where $Q_T$ is the total number of questions ever asked (i.e., including deleted ones), $Q_N$ is the number of questions with negative score, $Q_C$ is the number of questions closed, and $Q_D$ is the number of  deleted questions.  (Side-note: to be precise, questions closed and/or deleted only after 60 or more days do not count as closed or deleted here.)

Also note that a question that is negatively scored *and* closed *and* deleted will actually count towards all three on the right, so that you need five 'good' questions to balance this one.

Comment: How about duplicated once ?Are they counted in the form of close questions?

Comment: Yes, duplicate closed counts as closed.