# I do not get my Curious badge

Tags: support, bug, badges

It is the first time I ask something on Meta, so I hope this question is suitable. It seems like I have been '[curious](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/407/curious)' enough, asking 5 well received questions, but I do not get the corresponding achievement. Has anyone had the same kind of problem? Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Sometimes the badges take a while to be awarded.

Comment: Related: [What is a positive question record?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24803)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I have applied the formula I see in the last question you mention, but it seems it does not apply to my case. Maybe I just forgot some deleted questions. I will wait and ask more questions to see what happens.

Comment: It seems to me that your trend is very much ok, and you'll get this badge eventually. The two deleted questions from November and one from December are hurting your score now, but that will get fixed soon enough!

Answer (score 5):

I see that you "need positive question record" when I click the Curious badge on your account, which you haven't got yet.

In order to get "positive question record":

- Let $x$ be the total number of asked questions (including deleted questions)
- Let $y$ be the total number of questions score $-1$ or less (including deleted questions)
- Let $z$ be the total number of closed/on hold questions within $60$ days of being asked (including deleted questions)
- Let $t$ be the total number of deleted questions within $60$ days of being asked
- One question can be counted for all variables $y,z,t$ if it is qualified for multiple of these: "Negative"; "Closed/On hold"; "Deleted"
- To get "positive question record", you must have

$$x-y-z-t\ge 0.5x$$

You can see your own deleted questions to check if this is true. Your profile shows:

[image]

Here's an example of "positive question record" on my profile, it is supposed to look like this:

[image]

More information added:

- One of the moderators of this site, [Jyrki Lahtonen](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11619/jyrki-lahtonen) has checked your profile and stated that you had $12$ total questions, $4$ deleted, $3$ closed and $1$ with $\text{score}<0$. You need to ask $4$ more questions with score of $0$ or higher, not closed, not deleted to get the positive question record.
- I also add one more example in my profile. As main user, I have asked $14$ questions, all with $\text{score}\ge 0$, neither of them are closed or deleted. As meta user however, I have asked $5$ questions with $1$ negative score and $2$ are deleted, so I don't have positive question record here.

Comment: I have only one closed question in the list of the deleted questions. In my case $x = 9, y = 0, z = 1, t = 1$. So if I counted correctly $7 \geq 4.5$...

Comment: But how many deleted questions in total and negative-score questions? Also, this is a mathematics meta site so I have intentionally setting $x,y,z,t$ so it looks more like math.

Comment: Negative-score questions = 0. Deleted questions = 1.

Comment: Note that you can't even see your own deleted questions if it is deleted more than $60$ days ago. Do you remember having deleted any other questions at all?

Comment: I think there was one more deleted. Anyway I should have $6 \geq 4.5$, which is still ok.

Comment: Only moderators can see what any user has ever deleted, hope this case will be verified by a moderator.

Comment: As I said in the comments, maybe I am just forgetting some deleted questions. I will wait and see. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The data I see in Gibbs' profile says:12 questions total, 4 deleted, 3 closed, 1 with a negative score.