# Why is getting a question on hold with no down-votes result in "no longer accepting questions?"

Tags: discussion, post-ban

Recently, I've asked a question that was placed on hold. Asking if my calculations are correct. I made sure I wasn't broad and that enough details was given.

I then decided to delete it so that no one will downvote. Although, I found my answer now I can't ask questions no more. Why is that?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24803/what-is-a-positive-question-record) for what goes into a positive question record. Deleting a closed question is doubleplusungood.