# How to earn the inquisitive badge?

Tags: support, badges

It is mentioned that "Ask a well-received question on 30 separate days, and maintain a positive question record". So does it mean that on 30 separate days I have to ask different questions and all those questions should have +ve score?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, but this is not enough.

Indeed, a well-received question is one with positive score; it also has to be open and not deleted to count.

However, and possibly counter-intuitively, for a day to count for the 30 you must not have asked any question that is not well-received on that day. In other words, only days where you asked a question and where all questions you asked were well-received count towards the 30.

Finally, as said in the description, you need a positive question record. This takes into account all questions you ever asked, not only those on the 30 days. What it means exactly is explained on [What is a positive question record?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24803/what-is-a-positive-question-record) (also see [Why was the "curious badge" badge not being awarded?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23431/why-was-the-curious-badge-badge-not-being-awarded))

Moreover, [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) contains details for all badges.

Comment: That's quite helpful, @quid.  I had never known exactly the formula for a positive question record.  Also it is helpful to know badges available to askers.

Comment: @quid your answer was really clear and easy to understand.