# Earning a badge

Tags: bug, badges

Is it normal that I've completed the requirements (MSE acknowledges it) of a badge but didn't receive it? Or this is just a bug?

Here is how it looks like in my profile:

[image: proof]

The thing is the number of questions is calculated correctly (it's $7$ questions, but $2$ of them were asked on the same day).

[image]

I marked my question as duplicate, however the answers of that question doesn't seem to answer to my question, since for me $Q_N = Q_C = 1$ (this is the same question) and I don't know the number of deleted questions, hence 
$$8 + Q_D \ge 2 (2 + Q_D) \Leftrightarrow Q_D \le 4,$$
which I strongly believe $Q_D \le 4$ is true.

Comment: Badges aren't awarded immediately as I recall; I think there's a task that runs regularly to see if updates are needed and does them.  How long have you waited already?

Comment: it's been 3-4 days now and meanwhile I received other badges (like 3 of them).

Comment: Ok, then it looks like you have the number of questions required, but not the positive question record.  The badge info says "Ask a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintain a positive question record", but I'm afraid I don't know how to check your question record.  I know other users here do though.

Comment: The calculation of 6 is correct, that's the thing. I'll add another screenshot with a list of questions with maintained positive records.

Comment: It's your *overall* record, not the record for individual questions.  If you have a lot of downvotes or deletions then you can have a negative record even with upvoted questions.

Comment: are you saying that maintaining positive records doesn't mean having a positive question score? Even if so, I just manually checked that none of above questions have been downvoted.

Comment: Yes, it's more complicated.  See quid's answer here:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26711/how-to-earn-the-inquisitive-badge

Comment: ok, I found a very similar question and marked mine as duplicate.