# Why am I not getting the Inquisitive badge

Tags: discussion, badges

Why am I not getting the *Inquisitive* badge$?$ I completed the criteria nearly one and a half weeks ago but still the badge isn't coming. Is it a glitch from M.SE's side or something else.

[image]

Comment: Why is this tagged [meta-tag:moderators]? In what sense is this something related to the elected moderators, the actions they have taken, or the powers they have?

Comment: FYI, using a [site search](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquisitive), there's [How to earn the inquisitive badge?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26711), which links to the related [Why was the "curious badge" badge not being awarded?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23431) (in particular, its [answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/23432) explains about needing to maintain a "positive question record", as also explained specifically for your case in [davidlowryduda's answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/35898) below).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the inquisitive badge, you must have asked a well-received question on 30 days **and** maintain a positive question record.

You don't have a positive question record.

To calculate your question record, you count

$$
\frac{\text{NumQuestions} - \text{NumDV} - \text{NumCL} - \text{NumDEL}}{\text{NumQuestions}},
$$
where

- $\text{NumDV}$ is the number of downvoted questions
- $\text{NumCL}$ is the number of closed questions, and
- $\text{NumDEL}$ is the number of deleted questions.

Note that if a question is *downvoted, closed, and deleted*, then it counts *triple* against the record.

A record is *positive* if the calculated record above is at least $0.5$. I think (but calculated this very quickly and didn't check) that your record is approximately $0.39$. To get the inquisitive badge, you'll have to improve your question record — probably by asking more good questions.